# Rewrite unless resource exists

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-routing

I have the following rewrite rule which converts `example.com/anything/` to load the page at `example.com/anything.html`

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.html [L]`

I need an exception to this rule when a physical directory or file exists. For example, if there is a physical directory at `example.com/test/` then it should load an index from the `/test/` directory, instead of rewriting it to `example.com/test.html`

I believe I need rewrite conditions `RewriteCond` with `!-d` and `!-f` similar to:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write these conditions.

## Solution:

Prefixing the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Allows directories to be read as they usually would. Also my regex pattern match doesn't consider file names with extensions (lacking a dot `.`), so files such as `example.css` will be read as usual also.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: What was the problem you were having with these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you suggest, you need an additional *condition* to test that it is not a directory. For example, in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

The negated *CondPattern* `!-d` checks that the `REQUEST_FILENAME` does not map to a directory. The `REQUEST_FILENAME` variable (in a *directory* or `.htaccess` context) holds the absolute filesystem path of the file/directory that the request maps to.

I don't think you need to check for *files*, since a file shouldn't match the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$` - unless you have files without file extensions?

---

In the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource) you link to:

> ```
> RewriteCond "/var/www/my_blog/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" !-d
> ```

The format of this directive doesn't actually look correct to me, considering the example shows it being used in a *directory* context. (This format might be required in a *server* or *virtualhost* context, when the `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the same as `REQUEST_URI` - the URL-path of the request. However, this variable would then *starts with a slash*, so the above is still incorrect?!)

Comment: You're right that the pattern doesn't match files with extensions (example.css), so this is perfect.